# Add a "#" to an Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, materialize

The thing is that I have a card div in a View that when being clicked redirects you to another View; it is working fine and Im getting and URL like : `localhost:34195/Home/Details/1` , but I need to add a `#` symbol on the Id parameter for me to get an URL like `localhost:34195/Home/Details/#1` .

This is the div that calls the other View:

```
<div class="card z-depth-5" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home",new { id = item.Id })'">
```

Comment: `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home")#1'"`

Comment: @Liam I´ve fixed the issue in the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

After some help provided by an user that deleted his answer, I´ve accomplished what I needed by changing the onclick like this:

```
<div class="card z-depth-5" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "Home")/#@item.Id'">
```